# Couldn't Extend the infix-to-prefix-convertor to handle the power (^) operator

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, stack

i've implemented the infix-to-prefix converter using stack , the power operator has right to left association , which drove me nuts trying to implement it.

here is my code :

```
def infix_to_postfix_converter(string):
    def pop_untill_open_parentheses():
        while not stack.is_empty() and stack.peek() != '(':
            output.append(stack.pop())
        stack.pop()

    def pop_all_the_higher_precedences(operator):
        while not stack.is_empty() and precedence(stack.peek()) >= precedence(operator):
            if stack.peek() != '(':
                output.append(stack.pop())
            else:
                break
        stack.push(operator)

    def precedence(operator):
        operators = {'(': 3,
                     ')': 3,
                     '^':2,
                     '*': 1,
                     '/': 1,
                     '+': 0,
                     '-': 0,
                     }
        return operators[operator]

    stack = Stack()
    output = []
    for literal in string:
        if literal.isalpha():
            output.append(literal)
        elif literal == '(':
            stack.push(literal)
        elif literal == ')':
            pop_untill_open_parentheses()
        else:
            pop_all_the_higher_precedences(literal)
    while not stack.is_empty():
        output.append(stack.pop())
    return ''.join(output)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem? What is it exactly do that doesn't work?

Comment: @ARK1375 i want to handle the power operator (^) when converting an expression from infix notation to postfix notation .

Comment: this code is working no problems with it .

Answer (score 0):

so the solution is , if there is a '^' in the stack and another '^' came to be pushed it'll be pushed on top of the first '^' without poping it .

my solution :

add this compare function:

```
    def compare(operatora,operatorb):
    if operatora==operatorb=='^':
        return False
    else:
       return precedence(operatora)>=precedence(operatorb)
```

and modify the pop_all_the_higher_precedence function:

```
def pop_all_the_higher_precedences(operator):
 while not stack.is_empty() and compare(stack.peek(),operator):
     if stack.peek() != '(':
         output.append(stack.pop())
     else:
         break
 stack.push(operator)
```